# Allow a set of users on bokeh server with windows login

Tags: python, bokeh

I have a webapp using Bokeh, and I would like to only allow a list of users based on their Windows Login. Is it possible to fetch the Windows Login of the user of the webapp, check if in the list of allowed users, and let them in or not accordingly?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: Hello @MattDMo, thanks for your answer. Can you elaborate a bit on how I could do it?
Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it. You *may* be able to get help on the [softwarerecs.se] Stack Exchange, but *please* read through their [help center](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) **first** to ensure your question is on topic there.